# Reading files provided by the find command

Tags: c, shell, file

In my C program I am calling the shell command `"find . -name \"*.bin\""` using the following code:

```
FILE *fptr = popen("find . -name \"*.bin\"", "r");
```

Now I want to open each file this command finds in order to read the data from this file. I have tried with the following way but it isn;t working:

```
int numbers[5];
int i = 0;
char files[1000];
FILE *ptr;
FILE *fptr = popen("find . -name \"*.bin\"", "r");
while ( fgets(files, 1000, fptr) != NULL)
{
ptr = fopen(files, "r");
fscanf(ptr, "%d", &numbers[i]);
i++;
}
```

How can I manage this? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: *"but it isn;t working"* - What fails exactly?

Comment: The file doesn't open @StoryTeller

Comment: Where are you actually trying to *open* the file?

Comment: You're saying *The  file doesn't open* but what does that mean? You aren't checking `fptr` for NULL after you assign it from the `popen` call. You should check it. If it's not NULL, then the pipe opened.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am sorry, I hadn't included the commands to open the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `fgets(files, 1000, fptr)` commands reads the line and unless the line is too long or this is the last line without linefeed, `files` contains a newline.

Trying to open `files` fails because the filename has an extra newline. Since you're not checking if your file handle isn't `NULL`, you're not able to see that.

I would remove it safely like this (more techniques here: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input), the `strcspn` looks better for instance):

```
int l = strlen(files);
if ((l>0) && (files[l-1]=='\n'))
{
  files[l-1] = '\0';
}
```

then

```
ptr = fopen(files, "r");
if (ptr == NULL)
{
   // should not happen, but still...
   fprintf(stderr,"cannot open %s\n",files);
   exit(1);
}
fscanf(ptr, "%d", &numbers[i]);
```

Also don't forget to call `pclose(fptr);` when the loop ends to account for process termination & close the pipe (and if needed get the return code from the `find` command).

Comment: It is more succinct (no edge cases) to use `files[strcspn(files, "\n")] = '\0';` to replace the newline with a null byte.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right, I'm not familiar with those. I'm going to link with an answer which does that better (this was a "from memory" attempt to provide a fix, but it took me several edits :))

Comment: Both ways worked perfectly in my case. Thank you very much!